# Eunit assertions error reporting the wrong module

Tags: erlang, eunit

I started writing some functions to help test assertions on maps.

Let's say I have the following map:

```
#{a => 0, b => 2}
```

And after calling a function in my business logic I expect the map to look like this:

```
#{a => 1, b => 2}
```

In other words, I expect

- the map to have the same number of keys after the update
- the value of `a` to change from 0 to 1
- the value of `b` unchanged

I could just leave this test to pattern matching, however, if I have a large map with a lot of keys (and perhaps even a lot of submaps) it is not obvious where the problem might be - at least it takes some time to find the problem (maybe some values which I expected to be updated were not - or maybe there are some extra keys, etc, etc - I hope you get the point).

So as a start, I came up with the following helper function in my module:

```
-module(asserts).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

maps_assert_map_has_updated_values(BaseMap, Updates, ResultingMap) ->
    BaseMapKeys = lists:sort(maps:keys(BaseMap)),
    ResultingMapKeys = lists:sort(maps:keys(ResultingMap)),
    UpdatesKeys = lists:sort(maps:keys(Updates)),
    BaseMapWithoutUpdates = maps:without(UpdatesKeys, BaseMap),
    BaseMapKeysWithoutUpdates = lists:sort(maps:keys(BaseMapWithoutUpdates)),
    ResultingMapWithoutUpdates = maps:without(UpdatesKeys, ResultingMap),

    [
     ?_assertEqual(BaseMapKeys, ResultingMapKeys),
     lists:foldl(
       fun(Key, Acc) -> [?_assertEqual({Key, maps:get(Key, Updates)}, 
                       {Key, maps:get(Key, ResultingMap)}) | Acc] end,
       [],
       UpdatesKeys
      ),
     lists:foldl(
       fun(Key, Acc) -> [?_assertEqual({Key, true}, 
                       {Key, maps:is_key(Key, ResultingMap)}) | Acc] end,
       [],
       UpdatesKeys
      ),
     lists:foldl(
       fun(Key, Acc) -> [?_assertEqual({Key, maps:get(Key, BaseMapWithoutUpdates)}, 
                       {Key, maps:get(Key, ResultingMapWithoutUpdates)}) | Acc] end,
       [],
       BaseMapKeysWithoutUpdates
      )
    ].
```

I call this from another module, which is executed by eunit:

```
-module(map_tests).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

simple_map_test_() ->
    asserts:maps_assert_map_has_updated_values(
        #{a => 0, b => 2}, 
        #{a => 1}, 
        #{a => 1, b => 3}).
```

And I get the following error message:

```
asserts:30: maps_assert_map_has_updated_values...*failed*    in function asserts:'-maps_assert_map_has_updated_values/3-fun-8-'/3 (test/asserts.erl, line 31)
**error:{assertEqual_failed,[{module,asserts},
                     {line,31},
                     {expression,"{ Key , maps : get ( Key , ResultingMapWithoutUpdates ) }"},
                     {expected,{b,2}},
                     {value,{b,3}}]}
```

Which is *almost* what I want in that it reports the problematic key and the problematic values in the map, *however* it reports the error being in the `asserts` module, even though I am interested in seeing the actual test that failed, not the reference to the assertions module. I thought test generators were good for exactly that, but I wasn't able to get this working in that way.

Is there any way in which I can make `eunit` report the actual test module   (`map_tests`, function/test `simple_map_test` line X) instead of my `asserts` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the `?_assert...` macros are compiled into the `asserts` module, and that's where EUnit does its magic to figure out modules and line numbers (at compile time, that is). If you replace the `maps_assert_map_has_updated_values` function with a macro that you put in an header file that you include, you should see the right stack trace.

Comment: Hmm. Why though, after the "in function asserts..." line referencing "test/asserts.erl, line 31" is there not a "in call from" line referencing a line number in test/map_test.erl? Surely the problem here is not that the asserts module is at the top of the stack trace but that there is nothing after the top of the stack trace?

Comment: @Michael: In this case, your call to `asserts` is the last call in your test case function. Erlang makes tail call optimizations, removing that call from the stack. If you add another significant line of code after that call, you should be able to see it in your stack trace.